# Why doesn't extjs drop event behave like window.ondrop?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

This produces expected results

```
window.ondrop(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.dataTransfer);
});
```

However while trying to do something the sencha way I can't get expected results. The result is an unexpected undefined. The event will fire as expected, I just can't seem to get valuable data out of it.

```
click: function () {
  var myWindow = Ext.create('someWindow', {
    modal: false,
    id: 'drop-window',
  }).show();

  debugWindow.body.on('dragenter', function (e) { e.preventDevault; return false; } );
  debugWindow.body.on('dragover', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; } );
  debugWindow.body.on('dragleave', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; } );
  debugWindow.body.on('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.dataTransfer);

    return false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. For reference for those that don't understand ext very well, ext wraps the event in its own even object. You can access the original even by e.browserEvent